# Выделение ячейки DataGridView

Tags: c#

Написал вот такой код:

```
       int logicnotemptyscan = 0;
       GoodNotNumberTmp = new object[dataGridView3.RowCount, dataGridView3.ColumnCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView3.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null)
                {
                    logicnotemptyscan++;
                    dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else if (logicnotemptyscan > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    GoodNotNumberTmp[i, 1] = dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    if (GoodNotNumberTmp[i, 1].ToString() == GoodNotNumber[i])
                    {
                        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    else { dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red; }

                }
            }


        }`
```

[image: Скриншот]

Но в итоге получаю ненужное мне выделение ячейки [0,0].
Как в соответствии с моим кодом убрать данное выделение?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в конце метода написать

```
this.Focus();
```

где this - ссылка на окно приложения(ваш класс, который наследуется от Window).